# Bootstrap tooltip not showing text with special characters

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap Tool-tip is not showing text properly if it contains special characters or tags. Currently i have a text like `<checkme>test</checkme>` but its showing me only "test" in tool-tip. Tried escaping special characters but its not working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an example, it's difficult to know what your specific issue is. However, I took a couple seconds to throw together a working example in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/MDCeQ/):

```
<div id="hexcode" title="&copy; Jacob">
  My tooltip reads an HTML character code.
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#hexcode").tooltip({ trigger: 'hover' , placement: 'right' });
</script>
```

Additionally, if you wish to specify in the tooltip options object the text you want, JavaScript accepts/interprets Unicode sequences, as explained by [O'Rielly here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1786-how-to-insert-special-characters-in-javascript/).

**Edit** to reflect new info:

```
<div id="hexcode" title="&lt;checkme&gt;test&lt;/checkme&gt;">
  My tooltip reads an HTML character code.
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/MDCeQ/6/

Comment: Hi Jacob, i edited the question, this time its showing my actual question properly.

Comment: Updated my answer. Same idea tho: replace special characters with a hex code.

Comment: Just to use correct terminology: they're not hex codes (infact, there is no hex in your answer); they're HTML entities. `&#9733;` is an entity that uses hex codes to define it. Otherwise +1.

Comment: @pickypg, I knew it wasn't a real hex code but I didn't want to be confusing. I honestly didn't know what the non-hex version was called tho (I've always seen them called _html character codes_).

Answer (score 0):

In MVC exists an HTML Helper to interpreter a html special characters. This is @Html.Raw(Variable)